# Regex To Extract An Object From A JSON String

Tags: java, regex, json, string

I have `JSON` String I would like to extract a Field from it Using Regex. The field can be an `Object`, `Array`, `String`, `int` or any type. I Know the other way like looping through all the keys in the `JSON` and finding it. I would like to know, This can be achieved using `Regex` or not. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This can be achieved using Regex or not

Not reasonably, no, because regular expressions are not well-suited to interpreting structures like JSON on their own; as with HTML, you want a proper parser.

Instead, use any of the several Java libraries for parsing the JSON and then traversing its content; there's a list of them at the bottom of [the JSON site](http://json.org/) (I see [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) used a lot, but there are lots of options).

Comment: I hope I got the answer, Thank you for your time. If I have a fixed JSON then it would have been possible right ?

Comment: @CodeDecode: I don't know that it has to be fixed. I'd expect JSON libs to provide a way to ask what type a prpoerty's value is.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved through regex, but it is simply worthless, because the you have to parse out your own variables.

Anyway, lets say we have a method `getObject(String key, String JSON)`

```
public String getObject(String key, String JSON) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.format("\"%s\":\\s*(.*),", key));
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(JSON);
   if(matcher.find())
      return matcher.group();
   return null;
}
```

Note that this only will find the first occurence, you should modify this to your needs.
However, I do recommend a parser which parses the value for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use JSON deserialization tools (e.g. Jackson, GSON), get Object and check,