# How To Parse JSON Object Using Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, json

```
string sample = "{\"STACK_SIZE\":4,\"thes_stack\":[4,4]}";
```

how can I parse it using RE in C#?

Comment: check this question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525295/regex-to-extract-an-object-from-a-json-string

Comment: THANKS but these links does not solved my problem

Comment: Uhm ... why? Just deserialize the JSON. See Tamim Salem's answer.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>First of all this isn't a valid JSON, remove the backslashes.</strike>
Second, using a library like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) you can parse your sample.

```
string sample = "{"STACK_SIZE":4, "thes_stack":[4,4]}";

var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(sample);
```

that will parse it into a dynamic type, if you want something more strongly typed create your own class:

```
class StackInfo
{
    public int STACK_SIZE {get; set;}
    public int[] thes_stack {get; set;}
}
```

then you can deserialize into it:

```
string sample = "{"STACK_SIZE":4, "thes_stack":[4,4]}";

var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StackInfo>(sample);
```

But since you didn't put exactly what you need or exactly what your problem is with the suggestions in the comments no one can really help you.

Comment: That really helped me in understanding the process and well i am going to implement it as we were at holiday.thanks alot

Comment: "backslashes" here for the c# compiler to escape quotes. They are not part of JSON.

Comment: @Kamarey Ya I noticed, seems I was sleepy, anyways, fixed it.

Comment: Guys i knew that but I did not notice as I was in search of cored code Thanks again to all